# How can we rename the database name in MySQL 5.0

Tags: mysql

I am using `MySQL 5.0.`

I have created a database named `accounts`, but now I want to change the database name to `FinanceAccounts`.

How can I change the database name in `MySQL 5.0`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093/how-do-i-quickly-rename-a-mysql-database-change-schema-name

Answer (score 21):

I think there is only one way (besides renaming directory in the MySQL datadir which will fail for InnoDB tables):

- create new database (with new name)
- make dump of old database
- import dumped data into new database
- delete old database

To create the new DB:

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE new_database;
```

To create the dump of the old DB:

```
mysqldump -u "your_username" -p --lock-tables old_database > old_database_dump.sql
```

To import dumped data into the new DB:

```
mysql -u "your username" -p new_database  < old_database_dump.sql
```

To delete the old DB:

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE old_database;
```

Bear in mind that your permissions on the old DB will need to be deleted as well. See here for more info:
[Revoke all privileges for all users on a MySQL DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287377/revoke-all-privileges-for-all-users-on-a-mysql-db)

MySQL 5.1.7 to MySQL 5.1.22 had a `RENAME {DATABASE | SCHEMA} db_name TO new_db_name;` command but this one has been removed in MySQL 5.1.23 for being too dangerous.

Answer (score 18):

The best way is probably to rename each of the tables inside the database to the new name. For example:

Update: There are two steps here

1. Create a new blank database as you want say "new accounts"

   CREATE DATABASE newaccounts;
2. Migrate each table one-by-one

   RENAME TABLE accounts.tablename TO newaccounts.tablename;

See 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html
for more information.

Comment: We're talking about renaming a DATABASE... Renaming a table is no problem at all.

Comment: thats what he says: RENAME TABLE database_name.table_name TO new_database_name.table_name

Comment: That's correct - didn't think of that possibility. This method perhaps generate some issues with open transactions or current locks on that table. But nevertheless it's a solution. Sorry for my first comment!

Comment: from the mysql docs: As long as two databases are on the same file system, you can use RENAME TABLE to move a table from one database to another: `RENAME TABLE current_db.tbl_name TO other_db.tbl_name;`

Any privileges granted specifically for the renamed table or view are not migrated to the new name. They must be changed manually.

Comment: works pretty much instantly, no matter the size of the tables or how many indexes, etc. much faster and more reliable than using mysqldump.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL kinda sucks for this. The only solid reliable solution is to use phpMyAdmin.

Login > click Scheme > click "Operations" > find "Rename database to:" > write NewName > click "Go."

As simple as that. All permissions are carried over.

Answer (score 2):

here , I rename mydb database to ecommerce, you follow this steps, but usin phpmyadmin is to easy

```
CREATE DATABASE `ecommerce` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

RENAME TABLE `mydb`.`Articles` TO `ecommerce`.`Articles` ;

RENAME TABLE `mydb`.`Categories` TO `ecommerce`.`Categories` ;

RENAME TABLE `mydb`.`Utilisateurs` TO `ecommerce`.`Utilisateurs` ;

ALTER TABLE `Articles` ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Articles_Categories FOREIGN KEY ( Categorie_id ) REFERENCES Categories( id ) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;

DROP DATABASE `mydb` ;
```

Answer (score 1):

To Rename MySQL Database name follow the following steps:

```
1) Click the database name 

2) Click at Operations from the top menu

3) Type new database name Under Rename database to:
```

[image: Please check the screen shot]