# Revoke all privileges for all users on a MySQL DB

Tags: mysql

From: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/drop-database.html

> ...when a database is dropped, user privileges on the database are not automatically dropped.

So the question becomes, how do you revoke all privileges for all users on a MySQL DB? I imagine it's simple, but I'm surprised I haven't been able to find this anywhere.

Comment: You can use the [`revoke`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/revoke.html) command.

Answer (score 27):

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM '<user_name>'@'localhost';
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM '<user_name>'@'%';
```

Eg.:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM 'jeffrey'@'%';
```

Answer (score 21):

You can revoke all privileges for a specific user with [this syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/revoke.html):

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES, GRANT OPTION FROM user [, user] ...
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

> which drops all global, database, table, column, and routine privileges for the named user or users

Not sure if there's a way to do this for all users at once, though.

Comment: important to note, 5.5 at least the ",grant option" is required even though the user didn't possess the grant option

Comment: Thanks, however it's not clear how to run mentioned command with database, the following fails with SQL error - `revoke all, with grant on $dbs.* from 'user'\@'localhost'`. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES FROM '%'@'%';
```

The above could be dangerous as i suppose it will delete all the privileges from all the users including root

Modify it to:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES FROM 'user'@'localhost';
```

or

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES FROM 'user'@'%';
```

before execute

Comment: need ", grant option", at least with 5.5 for revoke all privileges

Comment: This is very very dangerous and not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES FROM '%'@'%';
This would only revoke a user that was created with %@%       not revoke all non users that had it specified differnt

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you can do:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES FROM '%'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

(Don't modify MySQL tables directly)

Comment: need ", grant option", at least with 5.5 for revoke all privileges