# How to remove user privileges associated with the dropped table?

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl, drop-table

When I was reading about the DROP TABLE statement in MySQL, I came across the term RESTRICT & CASCADE. On one website, [click here to goto that link](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-drop-table/#:%7E:text=The%20RESTRICT%20and%20CASCADE%20options,that%20you%20want%20to%20remove.) where I found information stating,

> Note that the DROP TABLE statement only drops tables. It doesn’t remove specific user privileges associated with the tables. Therefore, if you create a table with the same name as the dropped one, MySQL will apply the existing privileges to the new table, which may pose a security risk.

It made me curious to know how one can remove user privileges associated with the dropped table?
Also, what are the use of RESTRICT & CASCADE keywords in the DROP TABLE statement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Revoke all privileges for all users on a MySQL DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287377/revoke-all-privileges-for-all-users-on-a-mysql-db)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, but partially. Now I know how and where to look for more appropriate answers. Secondly, I also asked about RESTRICT & CASCADE. Please throw some light onto that. Also, if there is anything to do with or is there any relation with the dropping privileges, explain that to me please.