# query cache doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I have turned on query_cache, and allocated memory for it:

```
| query_cache_limit            | 1048576    |
| query_cache_min_res_unit     | 4096       |
| query_cache_size             | 16777216   |
| query_cache_type             | ON         |
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate | OFF        |
```

But queries are not cached:

```
| Qcache_free_blocks             | 1        |
| Qcache_free_memory             | 16768400 |
| Qcache_hits                    | 0        |
| Qcache_inserts                 | 0        |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes           | 0        |
| Qcache_not_cached              | 163      |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache        | 0        |
| Qcache_total_blocks            | 1        |
```

I use Innodb as storage engine, without transactions. The sample query which is not cached:

```
select * from `feed-ts`.feeds where id < 10;
```

It returns just one row.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's [a bug in MySQL](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=55556).

The query cache simply doesn't get used for queries on InnoDB tables that are in a database with a hyphenated name (like `feed-ts`).

"[Renaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093/how-do-i-quickly-rename-a-mysql-database-change-schema-name)" your database seems to be the only solution for now.

Comment: Oh, such a mess :-S Thank you

Comment: The bug is apparently fixed as of [MySQL 5.6.9](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-9.html).