# MySQL Query caching doesn't work from Application Server

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, query-cache

Below are my Query cache settings,

```
mysql> show variables Like '%query_cache%';

+------------------------------+---------+
| Variable_name                | Value   |
+------------------------------+---------+
| have_query_cache             | YES     |
| query_cache_limit            | 1048576 |
| query_cache_min_res_unit     | 4096    |
| query_cache_size             | 8388608 |
| query_cache_type             | ON      |
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate | OFF     |
+------------------------------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

when I execute queries from MySQL command prompt the caching is working and results are coming very fast. But for the same query from application its not working. Can you please advice me to resolve this issue. Im using Java with Tomcat server

Comment: did u got any exception?

Comment: No Exceptions, I expected some improvement in query response(have log in my application). But there is no difference from application after this setting

Comment: can u tell me what u want to do?

Comment: I have set Query cache configurations in MySQL, I see some difference in query response time when I execute in command prompt, But The same query when I execute from application I don't see any difference before and after setting query cache. I want to see some difference in query response after I set query cache settings in MySQL

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155373/query-cache-doesnt-work?rq=1  check this mate..u may find it interesting

Comment: Actually that happens when DB name has hypen in it. But my Database doesn't have any hypens. Also Query caching working from Command prompt. My problem I don't see it from Java web application

Comment: What version of MySQL you are using?

Comment: This is the version Im using, 5.1.69

Comment: Have you read this article? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-operation.html And to be sure your query don't hit cache, check `Qcache_hits` variable before and after run query on Tomcat.

Comment: I have read this, Also I checked this `Qcache_hits`. It gets incremented when I execute queries from MySQL command prompt. But it didnt when it via tomcat application

Comment: So, query don't hit a cache. Maybe stupid question, but query exactly the same in application and console? You run it on the same MySQL DB?

Comment: Yes, Both are exactly same queries