# how to delete schema without deletion of tables present inside my schema

Tags: mysql, schema, database-schema

I need to delete my schema when i created during table creation but i no need to disturb tables inside that schema  so please suggest me to delete my schema without deleting tables present inside that schema.

Comment: first of all do you know what is exactly schema?

Comment: can you explain why you want to delete the schema. in mysql, a schema is pretty much a database - see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_schema) for example.

Comment: schema which is used to hold multiple object @uvais

Comment: schema is only the structure , it can be structure of table or can be structure of database ok. you need to use databse instead of schema

Comment: and if you delete database all the tables related to this database will be delete

Comment: cleared right now thank you @ uvais

Comment: could u tell me exactly whether schema is for database structure or table structure ...i got confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mysql a schema is the same as a database. Removing the schema removes the database, and also your objects (ie tables)

Comment: Mysql have no RENAME SCHEMA or DATABASE, look at this guide http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093/how-do-i-quickly-rename-a-mysql-database-change-schema-name

Comment: yes thank you you are correct, could you give me the exact solution for my problem

Comment: Look at the linked answer, it will help you

Comment: it seems that we need to use for each table too complex is there any alternate solution?

Comment: Why do you need to rename? If you have a small db, dump it with mysqldump, drop db, create new, import dump

Answer (score 0):

you can not delete schema without deleting underlying tables, because schema is logical container which holds database objects like table, procedure etc..

you want to do like: breaking the glass(filled with water) without flowing water,
which is impossible,

best practice for your problem would be [`RENAME`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190000/rename-mysql-database) your schema. so it feels like schema is no longer available, but you can access it via different name.

Comment: RENAME will not work kindly see notification from  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/rename-database.html