# wordpress database connection on local server

Tags: database, wordpress

I have a problem with database connection on local server (Open Server).
I installed wordpress and created a new database. Everything worked well. But when I imported a database from remoted host I received a message during wp configuration process:

> We were able to connect to the database server (which means your username and password is okay) but not able to select the victo188_victoria database.

Are you sure it exists?

Does the user root have permission to use the `victo188_victoria` database?

On some systems the name of your database is prefixed with your username, so it would be like `username_victo188_victoria`. Could that be the problem?

DB exists. The user has the permission. With name everything is ok.

All the answers I've read on such topic were about you can't get connection to any DB. But i can't do it to the only specific DB

What can be the problem? Thank you.

Comment: what is the database host?

Comment: I imported DB from ua-hosting.org to localhost (Open Server)

Comment: Your question is still not well constructed. Lay out the problem before the sharing the code. Beyond the ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) advice, you also need to start by stating the question in a way that focuses on what gap remains _after_ your research. Then describe your strategy thus far, code setup + conditions, and the errors/issues. Also state 'obvious' context that you already know, so that people understand what you have tried. See also [1](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you, @New Alexandria. Today I've finally solved the problem via renaming DB. I created new DB with another name and imported my DB in it. Then it worked. I don't know what the problem was with that name...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190000/rename-mysql-database)