# Rename the database dynamically using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, dynamic

I am creating dynamic database with the help of dbforge in codeigniter
with this code -

```
$this->load->dbforge();
$this->dbforge->create_database('mydatabase');
```

Now I want to rename this database dynamically, but i am not getting such type of method related to **rename_database**

your solution will be appreciated.

Comment: You will have to use raw SQL: `ALTER DATABASE ... UPGRADE DATA DIRECTORY NAME`.

Comment: I can give you a specific answer if you tell me which database you're using =)

Answer (score 0):

see [How do I quickly rename a mysql database (change schema name)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67093/998759)

Basically, you can't (shouldn't) because it's potentially dangerous, so i guess that Codeigniter does not have any method for this. Anyway, changing the database name isn't something that the application should ever do.

Anyway, there are multiple ways depending on your database and/or engine listed in the linked answer.

Comment: You are right we can't rename the database dynamically, but I was in confusion so asked this silly question..