# Error create database with shell

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I come here for the first time because I have a problem when I want to create my database with doctrine and Symfony. When I want export my classes in my database I have this problem. I think everything is okay, doctrine find my base but can't create it. Also, I created my database named "symfony" in phpmyadmin.

I hope someone can help me, thank you so much :).

```
php app/console doctrine:database:create
Could not create database for connection named `symfony`
An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE DATABASE `symfony`':

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1007 Can't create database 'symfony'; database e
xists
```

Configuration file:

```
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: 255a33a57b471045aa29326785659c6b0
    database_path: null

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        # path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
```

Comment: What part of the error message `Can't create database 'symfony'; database exists` are you having trouble with?

Comment: Could not create database for connection named `symfony`
An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE DATABASE `symfony`':

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1007 Can't create database 'symfony'; database exists

Comment: Well it confirms that the database exists, so maybe start by deleting or renaming the existing db?

Comment: If you want to delete your database run: `C:\wamp\www\Symfony>php app/console doctrine:database:drop`

Comment: Okay, I thought all the tables will be create with the base but no. It's just the base. Thank you, I'm done with that ;).

Comment: @wbrancaleone if your question is solved could you be so kind and accept or upvote my answer below?

Answer (score 2):

To summarize:

The error informs you that a database with the same name was already created. There are three options:

(1) **Delete your current database without saving it, using MySQL command line**. If you want to delete your database run: `DROP database name_database`

(2) **Delete the database without saving it, using console**: `C:\wamp\www\Symfony>php app/console doctrine:database:drop`

(3) In the case you like to **save the content of your current database**. Rename you current database. As far as I know you cannot do this directly. This is a work around. First, create a new database using command line: `CREATE DATABASE name_old_database;`. Second, copy all tables to the new database `RENAME TABLE name_database.name_table TO name_old_database.name_table;`. Finally,`DROP DATABASE name_database`
See further info: [How do I quickly rename a MySQL database (change schema name)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093/how-do-i-quickly-rename-a-mysql-database-change-schema-name?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)