# How to rename database in MySQL without loosing data?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to rename my database by the following query:

```
RENAME DATABASE my_db TO newDB;
```

but its showing me the following error response:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
 corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DATABASE
 activation_server_db TO activationserver' at line 1
```

Please help me find where I am going wrong?

Comment: @codemania , hi I am new user on stackoverflow, what does this mean when you get votes in minus, as in this post I have -2 votes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093/how-do-i-quickly-rename-a-mysql-database-change-schema-name

Comment: @amir see this for your question about voating http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: @codemania , oh my GOD stackoverflow is a whole science :P , its really interesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use these few simple commands

```
mysqldump -u username -p -v olddatabase > olddbdump.sql
mysqladmin -u username -p create newdatabase
mysql -u username -p newdatabase < olddbdump.sql
```

or For InnoDB, the following seems to work: create the new empty database, then rename each table in turn into the new database:

```
RENAME TABLE old_db.table TO new_db.table;
```

You will need to adjust the permissions after that.

Answer (score 1):

I follow these simple steps:

1. Create new database
2. Backup the old database
3. Restore old database under new database

Answer (score 1):

You can use **mysqldump**

```
using mysqldump

mysqldump [OPTIONS] --database oldSchema > oldSchema.sql
mysql new_schema < oldSchema.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a dump of your db and then create a new db with different name with that dump.

If it is online you need to take ofline it for avoiding data loss