# Mysql rename database does not work

Tags: mysql, sql

Unable to rename the database with the following query. I am using mysql2

```
RENAME DATABASE a to b;

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'database a to b' at line 1
```

I am new to mysql. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I quickly rename a mysql database (change schema name)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093/how-do-i-quickly-rename-a-mysql-database-change-schema-name)

Comment: That command was removed see - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/rename-database.html. Use ALTER DATABASE instead.

Comment: @Giles - alter database a to b;   this also throws error

Comment: @Jeff Perhaps you should also read the links that Giles posted?

Comment: @Giles Feel free to add it as an answer, I'll upvote.

Answer (score 1):

That command was removed see - [dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/rename-database.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/rename-database.html) . Use ALTER DATABASE instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a new database and rename the tables so they will be in the new database, and the old one can be dropped afterwards.

Find more here: https://blog.marceloaltmann.com/how-to-rename-a-database-in-mysql/

But basically something like:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_new_database;
RENAME TABLE my_old_database.tbl_name TO my_new_database.tbl_name;
DROP DATABASE my_old_database;
```

Using the script from the link above will allow you to use all your tables, so this can be done almost automatically.

(I mean this: `SELECT CONCAT('RENAME TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT( table_schema,'.',table_name, ' TO ','new_schema.',table_name,' '),';') as stmt FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema LIKE 'oldSchema' GROUP BY table_schema`)