# MySQL InnoDB_Memcached cannot open table with minus char

Tags: mysql, memcached, innodb

I add a InnoDB Memcached mapping in innodb_memcache.containers:

```
INSERT INTO `containers` (`name`, `db_schema`, `db_table`, `key_columns`, `value_columns`, `flags`, `cas_column`, `expire_time_column`, `unique_idx_name_on_key`) VALUES ('ycn_cloud_battery', 'ycn-cloud', 'battery', 'uuid', 'mah|mah_alive_capacity|mah_charge_capacity|cycle|curr_temperature|average_current|curr_voltage|bms_safety_status|bms_flags|transaction_status|order_id|status|user_id|update_time|create_time|available_status', '0', '0', '0', 'PRIMARY')
```

Then InnoDB_Memcached reports `InnoDB_Memcached: failed to open table 'ycn-cloud/battery'`

After double checked, the problem comes from the database name `ycn-cloud` contains minus char.

How to make InnoDB_Memcached open the database?

Comment: Rename the database: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093/how-do-i-quickly-rename-a-mysql-database-change-schema-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had resolved my question.

InnoDB_Memcached plugin operators InnoDB data file directly. Database `ycn-cloud` is named `ycn@002dcloud` in MySQL file system. So change the `ycn-cloud` to `ycn@002dcloud` in innodb_memcache.containers.db_schema resolve the problem.

Comment: Are you sure this really fixed your problem?  This won't change the name of the database.

Comment: Yes, InnoDB_Memcached plugin can open the data table after changes.