# MySQL - foreign keys mixed up after renaming database

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

MySQL version: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, for osx10.12 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

My databases:

- mydb_nov
- mydb_develop

I imported a mysql dump into a database `mydb_nov`. After import finishes I delete database `mydb_develop` and rename `mydb_nov` to `mydb_develop`. This way I can ensure to have just a few seconds downtime and do not have to wait an hour or two until I can continue developing on my php application. To be exact: I do not rename the database directly (as MySQL removed `RENAME DATABASE` statement), infact I rename the tables. See the script below.

For renaming the database I use a script from the folks of percona: https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/12/24/renaming-database-schema-mysql/ (at the bottom of the page, method 2).

```
#!/bin/bash
# Copyright 2013 Percona LLC and/or its affiliates
set -e
if [ -z "$3" ]; then
    echo "rename_db <server> <database> <new_database>"
    exit 1
fi
db_exists=`mysql -h $1 -e "show databases like '$3'" -sss`
if [ -n "$db_exists" ]; then
    echo "ERROR: New database already exists $3"
    exit 1
fi
TIMESTAMP=`date +%s`
character_set=`mysql -h $1 -e "show create database $2\G" -sss | grep ^Create | awk -F'CHARACTER SET ' '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'`
TABLES=`mysql -h $1 -e "select TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables where table_schema='$2' and TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'" -sss`
STATUS=$?
if [ "$STATUS" != 0 ] || [ -z "$TABLES" ]; then
    echo "Error retrieving tables from $2"
    exit 1
fi
echo "create database $3 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET $character_set"
mysql -h $1 -e "create database $3 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET $character_set"
TRIGGERS=`mysql -h $1 $2 -e "show triggers\G" | grep Trigger: | awk '{print $2}'`
VIEWS=`mysql -h $1 -e "select TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables where table_schema='$2' and TABLE_TYPE='VIEW'" -sss`
if [ -n "$VIEWS" ]; then
    mysqldump -h $1 $2 $VIEWS > /tmp/${2}_views${TIMESTAMP}.dump
fi
mysqldump -h $1 $2 -d -t -R -E > /tmp/${2}_triggers${TIMESTAMP}.dump
for TRIGGER in $TRIGGERS; do
    echo "drop trigger $TRIGGER"
    mysql -h $1 $2 -e "drop trigger $TRIGGER"
done
for TABLE in $TABLES; do
    echo "rename table $2.$TABLE to $3.$TABLE"
    mysql -h $1 $2 -e "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; rename table $2.$TABLE to $3.$TABLE"
done
if [ -n "$VIEWS" ]; then
    echo "loading views"
    mysql -h $1 $3 < /tmp/${2}_views${TIMESTAMP}.dump
fi
echo "loading triggers, routines and events"
mysql -h $1 $3 < /tmp/${2}_triggers${TIMESTAMP}.dump
TABLES=`mysql -h $1 -e "select TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables where table_schema='$2' and TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'" -sss`
if [ -z "$TABLES" ]; then
    echo "Dropping database $2"
    mysql -h $1 $2 -e "drop database $2"
fi
if [ `mysql -h $1 -e "select count(*) from mysql.columns_priv where db='$2'" -sss` -gt 0 ]; then
    COLUMNS_PRIV="    UPDATE mysql.columns_priv set db='$3' WHERE db='$2';"
fi
if [ `mysql -h $1 -e "select count(*) from mysql.procs_priv where db='$2'" -sss` -gt 0 ]; then
    PROCS_PRIV="    UPDATE mysql.procs_priv set db='$3' WHERE db='$2';"
fi
if [ `mysql -h $1 -e "select count(*) from mysql.tables_priv where db='$2'" -sss` -gt 0 ]; then
    TABLES_PRIV="    UPDATE mysql.tables_priv set db='$3' WHERE db='$2';"
fi
if [ `mysql -h $1 -e "select count(*) from mysql.db where db='$2'" -sss` -gt 0 ]; then
    DB_PRIV="    UPDATE mysql.db set db='$3' WHERE db='$2';"
fi
if [ -n "$COLUMNS_PRIV" ] || [ -n "$PROCS_PRIV" ] || [ -n "$TABLES_PRIV" ] || [ -n "$DB_PRIV" ]; then
    echo "IF YOU WANT TO RENAME the GRANTS YOU NEED TO RUN ALL OUTPUT BELOW:"
    if [ -n "$COLUMNS_PRIV" ]; then echo "$COLUMNS_PRIV"; fi
    if [ -n "$PROCS_PRIV" ]; then echo "$PROCS_PRIV"; fi
    if [ -n "$TABLES_PRIV" ]; then echo "$TABLES_PRIV"; fi
    if [ -n "$DB_PRIV" ]; then echo "$DB_PRIV"; fi
    echo "    flush privileges;"
fi
```

At first everything is working as expected, but as soon as I restart my computer, foreign keys are messed up in the database.

f.e. does `mydb_develop/table1/fk1` reference `mydb_nov/table2/id` instead of `mydb_develop/table2/id`. If I rename `mydb_develop` back to `mydb_nov` and then rename `mydb_nov` again to `mydb_develop` everything is fine again.

Is there some "caching" of foreign key references in MySQL? Is there another system database like `information_schema` which has to be updated too after renaming the database?

Comment: Have you seen this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093/how-do-i-quickly-rename-a-mysql-database-change-schema-name

Comment: Yes, but they did not cover triggers... Most of the solutions are just renaming tables... The percona script is more complete in my opinion.

Comment: @RiggsFolly By the way the percona script was also posted in the thread you mentioned.