# Rename a database in mysql using linux

Tags: mysql

I created a database with the name of old. Now I need to change database name to new.
But,I did not know how to change a name?

Comment: You cannot rename database - its name is relative to directory name where its files are stored. Backup and restore with new name is the only option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I quickly rename a MySQL database (change schema name)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093/how-do-i-quickly-rename-a-mysql-database-change-schema-name)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the ability to rename a database has been removed from the spec for security reasons. What you will need to do is create a full dump of the database "old". Then you'll need to create a new database and re-import the data